# React Native - Show the first line of text in Bold

Tags: react-native

In my app, I have notes and I want to show the first line of my text in bold, like the picture below

[image]

The above screenshot is from Mi Notes App.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you split your note string in two and then it's easy to separate, this is a very simple example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TextComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleText: "Hi there,",
      bodyText: 'Redmi 3S/Prime will receive the MIUI 9 stable UPdate in mid-late December. Stay...'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
          {this.state.titleText}{'\n'}
        </Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={5}>
          {this.state.bodyText}
        </Text>
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```